# Question on calculation of electrostatic potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electric-fields, potential

Find the potential $\phi$ at the edge of a thin disc of radius $R$ carrying the uniformly distributed charge with surface density $\sigma$.

It can be done as follows.
By definition, the potential in the case of a surface charge distribution is defined by integral $\phi = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon}\int \frac{\sigma}{r}dS$. In order to simplify integration, we shall choose the area element $dS$ in the form of a part of the ring or radius $r$ and width $dr$ in (Fig.). Then $dS=2 \theta\ r dr$ ,$r=2R\cos\theta$ and $dr=−2R\sinθ\ dθ$. After substituting these expressions into integral $\phi = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon}\int \frac{\sigma}{r}dS$,
[image]

​we obtain the expression for $\phi$ at the point $O$:
$$\phi=− \frac{σR}{πϵ}∫ θ\sinθdθ$$.
By taking limit from $π/2$ to $0$

We integrate by parts, denoting $θ=u$ and $\sinθdθ=dv$:
$$∫θsinθdθ=−θcosθ+∫cosθdθ=−θcosθ+sinθ$$

which gives $−1$ after substituting the limits of integration. As a result, we obtain
$\phi=σR/πϵ$.

My question is why we have taken limit from $π/2$ to $0$ instead of $0$ to $π/2$

Comment: Please use MathJax for writing mathematical equations. Tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/474059

Answer (score 0):

Remember, this is potential. For electric field, we integrate with limits from r to infinite. Whereas, if we’re talking about potential, we should integrate from infinite to r. Why so, you may ask. Limits only determine the answer and don’t play any other role. Potential of a positively charged, electrically isolated body is always +ve. Even if we took the limits 0 to 2pi, we would have gotten -ve of this value, in which case we would just take the mod, since sigma has its own sign. -(-)=+